# Numeric value printing format options in R (decimal and digits)

Tags: r

I have a question about the numeric value printing format with global options

My global option is as below.

```
options(digits = 5)
```

It works as ...

```
# type 1
> 123.1234
123.12
# type 2
>1234.1234
1234.1
```

I want it working like below by modifying global options.**(without using round() function)** please see below result

```
> 1234.1234
1234.12
```

Anybody can help me?

Comment: The number of digits that you want to print is fixed? I mean you want two digits after the decimal no matter what.... is it?

Answer (score 2):

Use `formatC(x,digits=2,format="f")`

Output :

```
formatC(123.1234,digits=2,format="f")
[1] "123.12"
formatC(1234.1234,digits=2,format="f")
[1] "1234.12"
```

Comment: Thank you Minions, But I want  to apply this printing format globally with out using function. 

In SAS, prints like below.
13.123 -> 13.12   /     
123.1267 -> 123.13
This is what I want...